# Image Links Failing in IE8 when Chrome Frame is not present/disabled

Tags: jquery, css, nivo-slider, google-chrome-frame

If you take a look at the following website, you will see a slideshow at the top of the homepage. I am using Nivo Slider here, and it has been reported by our client that the links are not working in IE8.

http://youthsolutions.com.au/

The only thing I can think of is that the "slide-overlay" div which uses absolute positioning is somehow "blocking" out the layer underneath (even though it has a set width and should only be blocking the left side of the slide).

Any ideas? I'm all out.

Comment: its a bit messy in IE9 as well

Comment: Thanks. I assume the search box at the top and the newsletter form at the bottom are out of alignment?

Comment: The **Chrome Frame** plugin loads up fine in IE8, and your links work.

Comment: Yep, I assumed so. Unfortunately the client does not use Chrome Frame. IE is the devil!

Comment: I just *disabled* **Chrome Frame** in IE, killed it in task manager too, and the slider fails for links.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue found by many, I found there's some solutions given to it by others.

one solution is to change the nivo slider css right at the bottom like below,

```
.nivoSlider a {
border:0;
display:block;
background-color: #fff;
filter:alpha(opacity=0);
opacity: 0;
-webkit-opacity:0;
-moz-opacity:0;
-khtml-opacity:0;
}
```

to prevent other div's blocking this out try using `z-index` and give it a bigger value like `z-index:8`

Comment: Ok, I've added in the CSS above. Is anybody able to check it out for me? I'm on a Mac at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

well ie doesn't render images as well as other browsers do, well may be there as a mistake while saving for web and devices, do this, again use save for web and devices option and save as jpg and DONOT replace any files give them new names and then link those new files to nivo slider then test it, it should work